# Overwriting entities from another bundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine

We're writing a custom CMS based on Symfony2 and are currently working on the user system. Our bundle has defined a `BaseSiteUser` that contains all the most common properties that a site may need for it's user data, and a `SiteUser` that extends `BaseSiteUser` and defines a table for the entity.

The idea was that for each individual project we'd overwrite the `SiteUser` entity by creating a more specific one in the new project's namespace, or use the default one if we don't specify a new one.

Our bundle architecture looks somewhat like this:

```
OurCompany
  CMSBundle
    Entities
      BaseSiteUser.php
      SiteUser.php

CustomerName
  CustomerProjectBundle
  CMSBundle
    Entities
      SiteUser.php
```

Our problem is that we can't build the model so that the `SiteUser` defined in `CustomerName\CMSBundle` is used instead of the one in `OurCompany\CMSBundle`. Instead, we get this error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
  The table with name 'siteuser' already exists.
```

We tried consulting the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html), but that part has not been covered yet. Searching the web did not provide a solution, either.

We are using the annotation method for defining the model.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted my previous answer as it as wrong :). Just checked implementation of `FOSUserBundle`. They are using [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). So in your core `CMSBundle` define `BaseSiteUser` as `@MappedSuperclass` and in your overridden bundle just extend `BaseSiteUser`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's how our bundles are currently set up. The inheritance itself works fine, but overriding an entity is what we're struggling with.

Comment: You can set `OurCompany\CMSBundle\SiteUser` entity in as abstract class.

Comment: But you must have to create a blank `SiteUser` entity in each bundle if you want to get default entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution should work (pseudocode):

```
OurCompany   
  CMSBundle
    Entities

      /**
      * BaseSiteUser
      *
      * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OurCompany\CMSBundle\Repository\SiteUserRepository")
      * @ORM\Table(name="siteuser")
      * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
      * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
      *
      * DON'T USE EXPLICIT DISCRIMINATOR MAP (it will be generated automatically) !!!
      * @ ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"basesiteuser" = "BaseSiteUser", "siteuser" = "SiteUser"})
      */
      BaseSiteUser.php

      /**
      * SiteUser
      *
      * @ORM\Table(name="siteuser")
      */
      SiteUser.php  => class SiteUser extends CustomerName\CMSBundle\Entities\SiteUserCustom

CustomerName   
  CustomerProjectBundle   
  CMSBundle
    Entities
      /**
      * SiteUserCustom
      *
      * @ORM\Table(name="siteuser")
      */
      SiteUserCustom.php => class SiteUserCustom extends OurCompany\CMSBundle\Entities\BaseSiteUser
```

Don't forget to register your bundles in **AppKernel.php**.
If you want to be able to define new fields in **SiteUserCustom** add your **CustomerNameCMSbundle** to the entity-manager configuration:

```
orm:
  entity_managers:
    default:
      mappings:
        OurCompanyCMSbundle: ~
        CustomerNameCMSbundle: ~
```